# What is the different between MMI codes and USSD codes?

Tags: ussd

Can anyone explain me the different between **MMI**(Man-Machine Interface) codes and **USSD**(Unstructured Supplementary Service Data) codes ?

Comment: Note for context - both are talking about cellular standards, MMI is in GSM, and USSD is in 3GPP.

Comment: From quick Googling, does this page help? http://berlin.ccc.de/~tobias/mmi-ussd-ss-codes-explained.html